# trace e^(ix)[exp(ix)] using a common class complex

Tags: python, matplotlib, complex-numbers

Plot exp(ix) using python.

I am confused about the way I approached the problem. I tried to use the complex class but I ran into errors.

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.real + other.real,
                              self.imag + other.imag)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.real - other.real,
                              self.imag - other.imag)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag,
                              self.real*other.imag + self.imag*other.real)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.real} + {self.imag}j"

    def plot(self):
            plt.plot(self.real,self.imag)


def graph(func, x_range):
    x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
    y = np.math.exp(x)



complexs = Complex(x, y) 
complexs.plot()
```

I got errors from the type: "the f(x) can't generate a list but a scalar " to x and y must have the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following modification of your code (follow comments):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


class Complex:

    __slots__ = ('real', 'imag')  # to make class lighter and faster, may be commented out

    def __init__(self, real, imag):
        self.real = real
        self.imag = imag

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.real + other.real,
                              self.imag + other.imag)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.real - other.real,
                              self.imag - other.imag)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__(self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag,
                              self.real*other.imag + self.imag*other.real)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.real} + {self.imag}j"

    def plot(self):
        plt.plot(self.real, self.imag, 'ko')  # 'ko' for big black dots


def graph():
    complexs = list()  # to store created Complex() objects
    plt.figure()
    for x in np.linspace(-1, 1, 10):
        y = np.math.exp(x)
        complexs.append(Complex(x, y))  # create Complex() and append it to the list
        complexs[-1].plot()  # call method plot of the last Complex() in the list


if __name__ == '__main__':

    graph()
```

[image]